# PHP MYSQL: Redirecting Users ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, header

Am trying to redirect a user to a page if some condition are true but it keep redirecting to the first page whether or not the condition is true.
Here is my code:

```
if($level ="100_level")
{
    header("location:course_reg.php");                      
}else {
    header("location:course_reg_200_level.php");            
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the condition the value was being assigned to `$level` instead of condition checking. In any cases, the conditions is true.

To fix, Put double equal (`==`) to your if condition,

```
if($level == "100_level")
```

Answer (score 1):

when this happen, that means you have problem with your condition or your code. First of all, please change the equal sign to below.

```
if($level == "100_level")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1 = sign, you make level exactly equal to the right side of the sign.

If you check for ==, then you are making sure that it is in fact exactly "100_level"

Don't forget to put exit(); after your header redirect code.